# no response with Mouse or Keyboard in HoloLens Emulator

Tags: hyper-v, hololens

I installed HoloLens Emulator on Windows Parallels of Mac Pro. The Emulator can start. The main menu also appeared. However neither apps can be invoked. no response when clicking the mouse.

Could you shed a light what I missed? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the magic is done by the XDE which embed the Hyper-V image and forward the keys and mouse input to the hololens image.

To open the emulator, you can press **F5** on any HoloLens project (easy way) or you can launch it manually with this command line:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.14393.0\XDE.exe" /name "HoloLens Emulator 10.0.14393.1358.dngoins" /displayName "HoloLens Emulator 10.0.14393.1358" /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\HoloLens\10.0.14393.1358\flash.vhd" /video "1268x720" /memsize 2048 /language 409 /creatediffdisk "C:\Users\sebastiangambolati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.14393.1358\dd.1268x720.2048.vhd" /fastShutdown /sku HDE

I just suppose that you have installed the HoloLens Emulator version *10.0.14393.1358*.

[image]

Comment: I finally got what is 'wrong' :)  I did not know to run an app, it uses 'right button click' ! Now the input can respond. Thank you anyway for the comments and help!